# How to fix error: Array type required in Delphi

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I am using Delphi 7, I try to compile demo application called uWebBrowser (OSRDLLBrowser.dpr) in CEF4 Delphi and I am getting an error:

```
TempSrcOffset := ((dirtyRects[n].y * Width) + dirtyRects[n].x) * SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
TempDstOffset := ((TempScanlineSize * pred(TempHeight)) - (dirtyRects[n].y * TempScanlineSize)) +
(dirtyRects[n].x * SizeOf(TRGBQuad));
src := @PByte(buffer)[TempSrcOffset];
dst := @PByte(TempBufferBits)[TempDstOffset];
```

[Error] uWebBrowser.pas(455): Array type required

I understand, that  `src := @PByte(buffer)[TempSrcOffset];` is trying to assign value which is not array, but can you explain why and how to fix it?

Note:

Now I am working with these binaries:
https://github.com/salvadordf/OldCEF4Delphi using D7, OS XP 32 bit, works just fine.

Comment: Works Fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `PByteArray` instead of `PByte`

In newer Delphi versions you can apply `[]` indexing to typed pointer when complier directive`{$POINTERMATH}` is `ON` [(help)](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirspointermath_xml.html)

Before D2009 pointer arithmetics was realized only for `PChar (PAnsiChar)`, AFAIK